# Mongoose runValidators is ignoring match validator on update

Tags: javascript, mongodb, validation, mongoose, match

I've been struggling with this for quite some time and I may just be going insane.  I'm running mongoose 4.11.4 and I'm trying to make a basic update endpoint such that I can update a user's first name and/or last name and it looks like this:

```
app.put('/api/user',function(req,res){
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id),
        {
            $set:{
                firstName:req.body.firstName,
                lastName:req.body.lastName
            }
        },
        {
            new:true,
            runValidators:true
        },
        function(error,user){
            if(error){
                res.json(error);
            } else {
                res.json(user);
            }
        });
});
```

I have runValidators true and I'm explicitly using $set. The relevant part of the schema regarding first and last names looks like this:

```
    firstName: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        match:[
            new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]"),
            "First name only allows letters!"
        ]
    },
    lastName: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        match:[
            new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]"),
            "Last name only allows letters!"
        ]
    }
```

But my regex match is never getting validated, but if I were to leave just the first or last name out of my request then the unique validator checks and fails.  I'm at a loss, am I missing anything extremely obvious?